# BigQuery request find changes between tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table named tableA with the following format:
id val1 val2 val3 val4

Then I have a table named tableB with exactly the same format. 
I would like for each line in tableB to check if a line with the same id is present in tableA. 
If yes, I want to check if any value among the other columns differs between the 2 lines.
If any column differs between those lines, I want to add a line in a 3rd table ( tableC )
with the following format: 
id val1 val2 val3 val4 val1_changed val2_changed val3_changed val4_changed today_date

The "changed" columns can be null if no change occured.

Is there an "easy" way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

(you can aggregate to arrays to make the comparison easier, but then you will need to desaggregate to get into cols)

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION compareCols( a ANY TYPE , b ANY TYPE )
AS ((
 SELECT STRUCT(arr[OFFSET(0)] AS col1_ch, arr[OFFSET(1)] AS col2_ch, arr[OFFSET(2)] AS col3_ch, arr[OFFSET(3)] AS col4_ch)
 FROM (
   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(IF(av!=bv, bv, null) ORDER BY i) arr
   FROM UNNEST(a) av WITH OFFSET i
   JOIN UNNEST(b) bv WITH OFFSET i
   USING (i)
 )
));

WITH data AS (
  SELECT title, DATE(datehour) date
    , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datehour)=7, views, null)) col1
    , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datehour)=8, views, null)) col2
    , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datehour)=9, views, null)) col3
    , SUM(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datehour)=10, views, null)) col4
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.wikipedia.pageviews_2020` 
  WHERE wiki='en'
  AND title LIKE 'Presi%'
  AND views > 0
  AND DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2020-01-10' AND '2020-01-11'
  GROUP BY title, date
  HAVING col1*col2*col3*col4>53500
), data1 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM data
  WHERE date = '2020-01-10'
  ORDER BY col1+col2+col3+col4 DESC
), data2 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM data
  WHERE date = '2020-01-11'
)


SELECT data1, compareCols([data1.col1, data1.col2, data1.col3, data1.col4], [data2.col1, data2.col2, data2.col3, data2.col4]) changes
FROM data1 
JOIN data2
USING(title)
```

[image]